# how do i make selected query as alias to used in another subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, alias

i've tried to find an answer for my question but i cant found one that suit me. So, for example i have 2 tables which are students and tests. students have 2 fields student_id, name and for tests, test_id and student_id.
what i want to do is query to print student_id, name and total test that student did. my failed query is

```
SELECT S.student_id, T.TOTAL 
FROM students as S , ((SELECT student_id, COUNT(test_id) AS TOTAL
FROM tests
GROUP BY student_id) AS T)
WHERE S.student_id = T.student_id;
```

it returns

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS T' at line 2

how to make alias selected query to "temporary table" to be used in another subquery?
please give me easiest answer and also advanced answer in MySQL, so i can compare both answer to be studied later. Thank you

Comment: Please dont use comma based implicit joins. Instead, use Standard way of `Join`ing.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real different comma separated and the write join explicitly.
I would prefer to write the join explicitly its more clear what i'm doing there, since there are different join types [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html).

**With join explicitly**

```
SELECT S.student_id, T.TOTAL 
FROM students AS S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT student_id, COUNT(test_id) AS TOTAL
    FROM tests GROUP BY student_id
) AS T ON S.student_id = T.student_id;
```

**With Subquery in the select**

```
SELECT S.student_id, (SELECT COUNT(test_id) AS TOTAL
FROM tests
where tests.student_id = S.student_id
GROUP BY student_id) as Total
FROM students AS S;
```

**With your way**(*removed the extra braces from the sub query*)

```
SELECT S.student_id, T.TOTAL 
FROM students AS S , (SELECT student_id, COUNT(test_id) AS TOTAL
FROM tests
GROUP BY student_id) AS T
WHERE S.student_id = T.student_id;
```

[Live example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oarCendWPT7g1eDxnmAWXD/0)

Comment: so the problem of my query is on from students and used "comma" without using inner join, Sir?

Comment: No its not the error its only a preference how you write. Check my answer both queries should work. I think your error is that you have extra braces i have removed that please check again wether both working or not. And i'm not a Sir ;)!

Comment: ups, sorry hehe. i did removing the brace and it still won't work

Comment: Check i added a live example, both queries produce the same result. Unless you have a some else in the query